# Interstitial ad frequency capping not working as expected: ads showing with every request

Tags: admob, interstitial

I'm displaying interstitial ads in my app and attempting to optimize them using frequency capping. I've set the optimization rule as *"Show no more than 10 impressions per user per 1 hour"*.

[image]

However, I've noticed that ads are still shown with every request, and I'm not sure if they are evenly distributed over the course of an hour. Does this mean that if I make 10 consecutive requests within an hour, the ads will be displayed, but they won't be shown on the 11th request?

What I'm aiming for is to have these 10 ads evenly spread over the course of one hour, ensuring a homogeneous distribution that doesn't disrupt the user experience.

Comment: It may take 6-8 hours for the updates

Comment: already a few weeks taken, not 6-8 hours

Comment: @DaxeshV have you ever tested frequency capping ?

Comment: @actuallynoneed I'm having the same issue, but only on iOS. However, when the user does allow tracking in the App Tracking Transparency dialog it's working as expected